# How to set menu cursor position?

Tags: c, menu, position, cursor, ncurses

the standard position of menu in ncurses is 0,0.
Can I change It? If Yes, how?
I tried `move()` and `wmove()`, but result is not changed.
Thanks in advance.

PS: What I tried:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <menu.h>
#define GETMIDDLEX(w) ((COLS - w)/2)
#define GETMIDDLEY(h) ((LINES - h)/2)
#define ARRAYCOUNT(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]))
#define ENTER 10

MENU *startMenu = (MENU *)NULL;
ITEM **startMenu_items = (ITEM **)NULL;
char *startMenu_choices[] =
{
    "Play",
    "Exit",
};
int startMenu_choices_N, selItem_index = 0;
int startMenu_status = TRUE;
const int menuW = 6;
const int menuH = 2;

int draw_startMenu();
int remove_startMenu();

int draw_startMenu()
{
    startMenu_choices_N = ARRAYCOUNT(startMenu_choices);
    startMenu_items = (ITEM **)calloc(startMenu_choices_N + 1, sizeof(ITEM *));
    for(int i = 0; i < startMenu_choices_N; ++i)
    {
        startMenu_items[i] = new_item(startMenu_choices[i], "");
    }
    startMenu_items[startMenu_choices_N] = (ITEM *)NULL;
    startMenu = new_menu((ITEM **)startMenu_items);
    move(GETMIDDLEY(menuH), GETMIDDLEX(menuW));
    post_menu(startMenu);
    refresh();
}
int remove_startMenu()
{
    unpost_menu(startMenu);
    for(int i = 0; i < startMenu_choices_N; ++i)
    {
        free_item(startMenu_items[i]);
    }
    free_menu(startMenu);
    return 0;
}
```

There's not main function I thought It as a library for another program.

Comment: Please show what you tried.

Comment: The question only shows a fragment.  The cursor position will be determined by the position in the window from which `getch` or `wgetch` reads.

Comment: But when I try to move the cursor it's automatically moved to 0, 0

Comment: by function post_menu!

Comment: `post_menu` does not call `getch`.  If you provide a more complete example, you may get useful advice.

Comment: you could start by removing these two lines from inside the draw_startmenu() function:  `    int draw_startMenu();
    int remove_startMenu();`

Comment: 1) check the returned value from the calls to the ncurses library functions.  2) the menu to display is all "" so nothing will be displayed.

Comment: the `refresh()` function places the curses at 0,0 in the current window, unless the `leaveok` parameter has been enabled (it is not enabled in the posted code)

Comment: this is a link to the correct way to handle a menu in ncurses: <http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/menus.html>

Comment: Thanks a lot everybody!

Comment: ` int draw_startMenu(); int remove_startMenu();` <- error careless mistake (They should be out!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a function `set_menu_sub(my_menu, derwin(stdscr, 0, 0, 10, 20));` that's working very well!